# How to stop UpdatePanel when i click link button from causing whole page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

How to stop `UpdatePanel` when I click link button from causing whole page postback?

UpdatePanel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel_update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>  
    <asp:Label ID="comment_sub" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("review_headline") %>/>

    <asp:Repeater ID="repeat" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeat_ItemDataBound" >
      <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="top_review">
          <h3>TOP REVIEWS</h3>
          <a class="view_all">View all reviews(<%=top_view%>)</a>
        </div>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("commented_by") %>' Font-Bold="true" /> 
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="link1" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="link2" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="link3" EventName="Click" />                                                    
  </Triggers>        
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: when i click link button repeater only refresh bt whole page posts back. how to solve this issue

Comment: Have you added asp:ScriptManger ? If yes than set EnablePartialRendering="true" in it.

Comment: yes,i added asp:ScriptManger and enabled EnablePartialRendering="true"  also bt everything post back

Comment: Have you set EnablePageMethods="true" also ?

Comment: IS link button in Repeater/Grid ?

Comment: i used outside repeater

Comment: yes i set EnablePageMethods="true" @ Mairaj Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

Set   ChildrenAsTriggers="true"  on your UpdatePanel control. closing tag for update panel should be